# Help needed with AI generated texture

Tags: texturing

I need to process sets of pictures (1 to 10 real life photos) from mammals to produce 3d models.
I need to automate this process:
1. normalise color among the set;
2. turn the set of real photos into a color texture. The 3d model and the texture layout is always the same for a specific species. I guess image reconstruction is needed;
3. extract the size parameters from the set (distance between eyes, legs, etc.)

Could you point me to the right techniques, people or organization to achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Answer (score 1):

You should ask this question in [computer graphic exchange](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/).

Hiring some 3D artist for these job is a good option, seriously. If you find out the solution, Please submit your work to SIGGRAPH or any top-level conference. That's not an easy job for now but, yes, doable. And I don't think Blender can do anything for you except opening a finished 3D model or showing the result or provide a playground for 3D tweaking.

Answer for the question:

#### 1. Normalize color among the set

A lot of work, just go searching "normalized color python".

#### 2. Turn the set of real photos into a color texture.

Are the photo always take as the same angle? The animal type? If the photo has no obvious description point. It will be very hard to tell computer to recognize them. It's called **feature mapping**.

Also you will need to reconstruct the 3D model.

#### 3. Extract the size parameters from the set

This is the most easiest part among these step. If you got Step.2 done correctly, you can directly know those 3-dimension coordinate of parts. Just calculate them using Euclidean distance.

Comment: And you only need to ask the step 2 of your question. Step 1 and Step 3 is just context and scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.